# Where can I find the pseudo code for a priority queue?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I am looking to implement it in Java, but I need to make specific changes to the code. I do not want to import PriorityQueue, instead for learning purposes I want to reinvent the wheel and do it from scratch but I feel I overcomplicated my code. So I was hoping to get set on the right track.

Comment: Maybe I should have specified, I want to used either a linked or double linked list

Comment: Show us what code you have used so far so we can tell you what you could/should change.

Comment: I have managed to make it work with 3 special cases (bound cases and if its empty) and then a while loop that adds items in between elements. I feel my code is a bit messy that is why I think I am overcomplicating

Comment: Yes, but please show us the code you have tried.  It'll make it much easier for people to give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here.

http://www.comp.dit.ie/rlawlor/Alg_DS/heaps/PQs%20and%20Heaps.pdf

I guess you can open any book or presentation or tutorial
on priority queues. Btw, this is not a complex structure so 
don't give up at all. I would try implementing a heap, 
it is quite intuitive and not hard to implement.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

You might also try some books (the one suggested by Arthur) plus this one.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Comment: I have both Sedgewick and the one you've suggested - burn yours and buy Sedgewick ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Algorithms by Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) contains 27 very good pages on Priority Queues in Java. I would highly recommend this book.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion

Comment: Small correction: it's Sedgewick.

Comment: @peter.petrov: indeed

Answer (score 1):

How about the source code:

[OpenJDK 6 - Priority Queue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue)

It's not exactly pseudocode, but since you're gonna implement it in Java it might provide you with some good language-specific pointers.